# Factoring out $httpProvider and interceptor from main js throws unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to move some config out of the main js file. I'm having problems with the step where I push the http interceptor on the $httpProvider.interceptor array, saying that it is an unknown provider. My interceptor is a factory function that lives in a file in the services directory and is appended to module.exports and required/bundled in with browserify. Currently the app errors with a

> angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $Provider <- $ <- myHttpInterceptor <- $http <- $templateRequest <-
>   $route
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24Provider%20%3C-%20%2…Interceptor%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24route

I had this working in the main app.js file, but trying to factor it out is proving to be harder than I expected. It looks like $httpProvider is undefinded inside the $httpProvider block.

```
// in app.js
.factory('myHttpInterceptor', ['$injector', '$location', '$q', '$rootScope', '$', services.myHttpInterceptor])
.config(['$httpProvider', providers.httpProvider])

providers.httpProvider : require('./config/http-provider')
services.myHttpInterceptor : require('./services/myHttpInterceptor')

// in http-provider.js
function httpProvider ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {}
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'
    };
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {}
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {}
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor') // <<-- Fails here in the debugger
}])
module.exports = httpProvider

// in myHttpInterceptor.js
function myHttpInterceptor ($injector, $location, $q, $rootScope, $) {
    // I did not put jquery in this project ;)
    ...
}
module.exports = myHttpInterceptor
```

Let me know if I can provide more info. Thanks for the help!

**Update**

It would be unwise for me to include the entire app bootstrap file, because it is quite extensive, but here's a look to see how it starts up:

```
var angular = require('angular'),
    $ = require('./jquery.js');

(function (angular, config, controllers, services, directives, filters, providers, $) {
    angular
        .module('***', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', ...])
})(

angular, 
//config obj
{...},
// controllers obj
{...}
// etc ...
)
```

All of the modules required at the top are defined and usable. I can stop the debugger after requiring jquery and it allows me to query the DOM with it in the console.

Comment: what version of angular are you using? also follow the instructions on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http if you pay attention they are using the $provide service from within the config block. lmk if you need more details

Comment: Error message says it all. `$` service isn't defined.

Comment: If $ exists and is defined outside the scope of this config block, what is the key to injecting it here?

Comment: @estus I checked out your recommendation. The $ obj is indeed defined in the outer scope. So how does it end up being undefined when I get to here: $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor') ??